Enabling Dark Mode in Chromium with C++
I am modifying the Chromium browser using C++. The version of my Chromium is 126.0.6478.122. What I specifically want to do is modify the C++ code at the right places so that a JSON file is read, where there is a boolean parameter indicating whether the Dark Mode should be enabled or not. The read boolean parameter should then be set accordingly in the Chromium C++ code.
I have found the runtime flag --force-dark-mode but this only changes the browser to dark mode for the next start of the browser. In the source code I found the function bool NativeTheme::IsForcedDarkMode() in the file ui/native_theme/native_theme.cc. This seems to read the dark mode parameter from the command line:
bool NativeTheme::IsForcedDarkMode() {
  static bool kIsForcedDarkMode =
      base::CommandLine::ForCurrentProcess()->HasSwitch(
          switches::kForceDarkMode);
  return kIsForcedDarkMode;
}


Apparently one also needs the flag --enable-features=WebContentsForceDark to change the color of the pages to the dark theme. I think the corresponding part in the C++ code is this one
  bool force_dark_mode_enabled =
      base::FeatureList::IsEnabled(blink::features::kForceWebContentsDarkMode)
          ? true
          : pref_defaults.force_dark_mode_enabled;
  registry->RegisterBooleanPref(prefs::kWebKitForceDarkModeEnabled,
                                force_dark_mode_enabled);


in the function void PrefsTabHelper::RegisterProfilePrefs in the file chrome/browser/ui/prefs/prefs_tab_helper.cc
How can I change the C++ code base such that the the flags which need to be set are instead read from a JSON file (for example). I suppose that the reading would necessarily to be done asynchronously in another thread.
Essentially, I want to have a settings like file where I can set whether the browser should start in dark mode or not.
I appreciate any help a lot, thanks.

You have found the right file where themes are set for the browser. Why not set breakpoint and study the code? You should be reading JSON file from some where around there because AFAI remember, that's where themes are applied too
